# icu and converter from memory

Tags: icu

I want to create an converter from memory.

I have created the etrypoint_dat and then the c file from my converter and joined the two struct together:

```
 },
    "", 1, 0, {
      { "ibm-5348_P100-1997", (const void *)&ibm_5348_P100_1997_cnv }
  }
```

From the code I call

```
  udata_setAppData("icupackage.dat", &ntrypoint_dat, &status); // return is good
```

Now my question:
How do I create the converter after the call fo setAppData?

The following does not work:

```
 UConverter* conv = ucnv_open("ibm-5348_P100-1997", &status);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself.

The connection between the two structs must be named in this way:

```
{ "icupackage.dat/ibm-5348_P100-1997.cnv", (const void *)&ibm_5348_P100_1997_cnv },
```

then from code we can call:

```
  status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
  udata_setAppData("icupackage.dat", &ntrypoint_dat, &status);
```

and then:

```
  status = U_ZERO_ERROR;    
  _cnvCP1252 = ucnv_openPackage("windows", "ibm-5348_P100-1997.cnv", &status);
```

The `.dat` should be deleted. I leave it for consistences with the question.

Comment: I make a typing error. The package has the name "icupackage.dat".

_cnvCP1252 = ucnv_openPackage("icupackage.dat", "ibm-5348_P100-1997.cnv", &status);
@manfred

Answer (score 0):

I would instead suggest that you use the pkgdata tool with mode 'static' which will build a static library for you to link.  This other example is the undocumented and fragile fragile way.

Comment: Yes, I have found that the way above does not work in all circumstances and therefore I switched to pkgdata in static mode.

Comment: Please file a bug if there's something unclear about how to use things or if you have any suggestions. Thanks for using ICU.